# Open ID and Wordpress Self hosted blog

Tags: support, openid, wordpress-se

I recently moved my blog to Linode and Open ID on SO and other meta sites seems broken.
SO says,
No OpenID endpoint found.
So, I tested my open id on http://test-id.org and it responded with a totally meaningless error

> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.

The open id I'm using is my blog URL, blog.mugunthkumar.com and the "Recent logs" at test-id.org shows this

> 2011-06-08 21:02:48,872 (GMT-7) [8]
>   DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Http - HTTP GET
>   http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/
>   2011-06-08 21:02:49,497 (GMT-7) [8]
>   DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Yadis -
>   X-XRDS-Location found in HTML
>   Http-Equiv tag.  Preparing to pull
>   XRDS from
>   http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/?xrds
>   2011-06-08 21:02:49,497 (GMT-7) [8]
>   DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Http - HTTP GET
>   http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/?xrds
>   2011-06-08 21:03:50,435 (GMT-7) [8]
>   ERROR Global - An unhandled exception
>   was raised. Details follow:
>   System.Web.HttpUnhandledException:
>   Exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException'
>   was thrown. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The
>   underlying connection was closed: The
>   connection was closed unexpectedly.
>   at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

I tried reinstalling WP-OpenID plugin and enabled php-curl as well. The status page on OpenID says everything is "ok".

What could possibly be the problem?